# Detect view change on ViewPager

Tags: android, android-viewpager

I am implementing a horizontally by library ViewPager ViewPagerExtensions (com.astuetz.viewpager.extensions) by SwipeyTabsAdapter. Is there anyway to intercept when a change of view? in the same way, i could know in what view is the user at all times?

The code of ViewPager

```
public class DiccionariuPagerAdapter extends PagerAdapter {

    protected transient Activity mContext;

    private int mLength = 0;

    public DiccionariuPagerAdapter(Activity context, int length) {
        mContext = context;
        mLength = length;
    }

    @Override
    public int getCount() {
        return mLength;
    }

    @Override
    public Object instantiateItem(View container, int position) {

        RelativeLayout v = new RelativeLayout(mContext);

        View vi; // Creating an instance for View Object
        LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater)mContext.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);

        if (position == 0) {            
            vi = inflater.inflate(R.layout.diccionariu, null);
        }
        else if (position == 1) {
            vi = inflater.inflate(R.layout.conxugar, null);
        }
        else {
            vi = inflater.inflate(R.layout.traducir, null);
        }

        v.addView(vi);

        //v.addView(t);

        ((ViewPager) container).addView(v, 0);

        startUpdate(container);

        return v;
    }

    @Override
    public void destroyItem(View container, int position, Object view) {
        ((ViewPager) container).removeView((View) view);
    }

    @Override
    public boolean isViewFromObject(View view, Object object) {
        return view == ((View) object);
    }

    @Override
    public void finishUpdate(View container) {}

    @Override
    public void restoreState(Parcelable state, ClassLoader loader) {}

    @Override
    public Parcelable saveState() {
        return null;
    }

    @Override
    public void startUpdate(View container) {}

}
```

thank you very much

Answer (score 9):

To get the current item use:

```
int itemId = ViewPager.getCurrentItem()
```

With that you can retreive the actual View from your adapter with

```
Adapter.getItem(itemId)
```

You can also use the listener `OnPageChangeListener`

```
viewPager.setOnPageChangeListener(new OnPageChangeListener...
```

Answer (score 5):

compiles & works:

~~~

```
    mPager.setOnPageChangeListener(new OnPageChangeListener()
    {
        @Override
        public void onPageSelected(int position) 
        {
                // if listener is set - when using an indicator, must update that here
                mIndicator.setCurrentItem(position);

                String msg = "onPageSelected - position: " + position;
                Log.d("debug1", msg);
        }

        @Override
        public void onPageScrollStateChanged(int state) {}

        @Override
        public void onPageScrolled(int position, float arg1, int arg2) {}
    });
```

Comment: `setOnPageChangeListener` is deprecated now, but we can use `addOnPageChangeListener` / `removeOnPageChangeListener` instead.